# Does anyone encounter unuseful rootpath in resteasy

Tags: java, resteasy

I'm using RESTEasy to write a example of WebService, and set the root resource path.But I find that even no root path in the url, I still can get the right resource.

Main function Code:

```
   NettyJaxrsServer netty = new NettyJaxrsServer();
    ResteasyDeployment deploy = new ResteasyDeployment();
    List<Object> resources = new ArrayList<Object>();
    resources.add(new UserService());
    deploy.setResources(resources);
    netty.setDeployment(deploy);
    netty.setPort(8180);
    netty.setRootResourcePath("/hello/");
    netty.setSecurityDomain(null);
    netty.start();
```

Service Code:

```
@Path("user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserService {
```

For the code, url /user can work normal, no need to add root path of /hello. I checked the source code; it adds the root path by itself.

source code:

```
public static String getEncodedPathInfo(String path, String contextPath)
{
    if(contextPath != null && !"".equals(contextPath) && path.startsWith(contextPath))
        path = path.substring(contextPath.length());
    return path;
}
```

My question is why RESTEasy do this? I can't understand.